# 'time' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration

Tags: pine-script

I'm following the best practices by PineCoders for Pine and I realized that there is no such type as `time`. What should I do in the following scenario?

> 'time' is not a valid type keyword in variable declaration

Note that I could easily remove the `time` prefix from `i_startDateTime` and `i_endDateTime` and solve the issue but I want it to be using the best practices. Just like LucF goy did https://www.tradingview.com/script/Xh8tLDTe-Delta-Volume-Realtime-Action-LucF/.

```
var string START_TIME = "2018-01-01T00:00"
var string END_TIME = "2030-01-01T00:00"

var string GP12 = "Date range filtering"
bool    i_dateFilter = input(false, "Date Range Filtering", group = GP12)
time    i_startDateTime = input(timestamp(START_TIME), "Start Date/Time", type = input.time, group = GP12)
time    i_endDateTime = input(timestamp(END_TIME), "End Date/Time", type = input.time, group = GP12)

f_tradeDateIsAllowed() => i_dateFilter ? (time >= i_startDateTime and time <= i_endDateTime) : true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp()` function returns an `int`, so your variable must be declared as an `int` too, or just omit `int` when defining the variable.

```
//@version=4
study("Time", "T", overlay=true)

var string START_TIME = "2018-01-01T00:00"
var string END_TIME   = "2030-01-01T00:00"

var string  GP12            = "Date range filtering"
var bool    i_dateFilter    = input(false, "Date Range Filtering", group = GP12)
var int     i_fromDate      = input(timestamp(START_TIME), "Start Date/Time", type = input.time, group = GP12)
var int     i_toDate        = input(timestamp(END_TIME),   "End Date/Time",   type = input.time, group = GP12)

plot(na)
```