# Replacing valuewhen in order to follow code optimization guide by PineCoders

Tags: pine-script

I'm reading P[ineCoders' FAQ](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-optimize-pine-code) and more precisely how to optimize the code. I want to replace `valuewhen` in the following scenario. I assume they mentioned it because of the warning about repainting when creating alerts?

> Use techniques like [this one](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-save-a-value-or-state-for-later-use) whenever you can, to avoid using valuewhen().

How should I avoid `valuewhen` in the following case?

```
EntryPrice = valuewhen(EnterLong or EnterShort, close, 0)
```

In my understanding before pine version 4, it was:

```
EntryPrice = 0, EntryPrice := nz(EntryPrice[1])
```

Now it should be:

```
var float entryPrice = na
if enterLong or enterShort
    entryPrice := close
```

Is that correct?

#### Complete snippet:

```
//@version=3
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders

// Signal for Backtesting-Trading Engine [PineCoders]
//  v1.3, 2019.06.21 02:58

// PineCoders, Tools and ideas for all Pine coders.
// This script is referenced from the PineCoders FAQ & Code here: http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-use-one-scripts-output-as-an-input-into-another
// Documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/script/y4CvTwRo-Signal-for-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/

// This script is an example of how to configure a signal for the PineCoders Backtesting-Trading Engine
// which you will find here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/
// We used the built-in MACD indicator as a template. The script's signal adheres to the following protocol:

// EXTERNAL SIGNAL PROTOCOL
//      Only one external indicator can be connected to a script; in order to leverage its use to the fullest,
//      the engine provides options to use it as either and entry signal, an entry/exit signal or a filter.
//      When used as an entry signal, you can also use the signal to provide the entry stop. Here’s how this works.
//        - For filter state: supply +1.0 for bull (long entries allowed), -1.0 for bear (short entries allowed).
//        - For entry signals: supply +2.0 for long, -2.0 for short.
//        - For exit signals: supply +3.0 for exit from long, -3.0 for exit from short.
//        - To send an entry stop level with entry signal: Send positive stop level for long entry
//          (e.g. 103.33 to enter a long with a stop at 103.33), negative stop level for short entry
//          (e.g. -103.33 to enter a short with a stop at 103.33). If you use this feature,
//          your indicator will have to check for exact stop levels of 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0 and their negative counterparts,
//          and fudge them with a tick in order to avoid confusion with other signals in the protocol.
//      Note that each use must be confirmed in the corresponding section of the script's Settings/Inputs.

// CONFIGURATION OF ALERTS
//      Entry and Event alerts will generally be configured to trigger Once Per Bar Close.
//      Exit alerts can be configured to trigger Once Per Bar Close or Once Per Bar, depending on how fast
//      you want them. Once Per Bar means the alert will trigger the moment the condition is first encountered
//      during the realtime bar, instead of at the bar's close.
//      Entry and Exit alerts trigger at the same bar where the relevant marker will appear on the chart.
//      Event alerts trigger on the bar following the appearance of their respective marker on the chart.

study("Signal for Backtesting-Trading Engine [PineCoders]")

// Allow selection of signal content.
IncludeFilter   = input(true, "Include Filter")
IncludeEntries  = input(true, "Include Entries")
IncludeStops    = input(true, "Include Stops with Entries")
IncludeExits    = input(true, "Include Exits")


// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// ▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
// This part is the section where you would put your own indicator and define conditions.

// ————— TV built-in MACD code.
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)

// ————— Filter.
FilterLong  = MACD>0
FilterShort = MACD<0

// ————— Entries.
EnterLong  = crossover(MACD, 0)
EnterShort = crossunder(MACD, 0)

// ————— Stops.
Atr = atr(14)
StopLong  = min(lowest(5), min(close,open) - Atr * 1.5)
StopShort = max(highest(5), max(close,open) + Atr * 1.5)

// ————— Exits.
ExitLong  = crossunder(MACD, aMACD) and MACD > 0
ExitShort = crossover(MACD, aMACD) and MACD < 0

// ▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

EntryPrice = valuewhen(EnterLong or EnterShort, close, 0)

// ————— This function ensures that no stop value equal to one of the protocol's reserved values is sent, so it isn't misinterpreted as a signal.
// The fudge is in the direction where the trade's risk is decreased by a tick, so added for longs and subtracted for shorts.
FudgeStop( _stop, _fudgedir) => _stop == 1.0 or _stop == 2.0 or _stop == 3.0 ? _stop + syminfo.mintick * _fudgedir : _stop

// ————— Build required values corresponding to states.
Filter = FilterLong ? 1 : FilterShort ? -1 : 0
Entries = EnterLong ? 2 : EnterShort ? -2 : 0
Stops = EnterLong ? FudgeStop(StopLong, 1) : EnterShort ? -FudgeStop(StopShort, -1) : 0
Exits = ExitLong ? 3 : ExitShort ? -3 : 0

// ————— We must decide which value will be sent in case more than one is different than 0, since only one value can be sent at each bar.
// Priority is given to exits, with filter states coming last.
Signal = IncludeExits and Exits != 0 ? Exits : IncludeStops and Stops != 0 ? Stops : IncludeEntries and Entries != 0 ? Entries : IncludeFilter and Filter != 0 ? Filter : na

// ————— Plot signal which is to be connected to the Engine through the External Indicator field at the very bottom of the Engine's Settings/Inputs.
plot( Signal, "Signal")


// ————— Plots markers.
plotshape(IncludeEntries and EnterLong,     "Enter Long",   style=shape.triangleup,     location=location.bottom,   color=green,    size=size.small,    text="Enter\nLong")
plotshape(IncludeEntries and EnterShort,    "Enter Short",  style=shape.triangledown,   location=location.top,      color=red,      size=size.small,    text="Enter\nShort")
plotshape(IncludeExits and ExitLong,        "Exit Long",    style=shape.triangledown,   location=location.top,      color=green,    size=size.tiny,     text="Exit\nLong")
plotshape(IncludeExits and ExitShort,       "Exit Short",   style=shape.triangleup,     location=location.bottom,   color=red,      size=size.tiny,     text="Exit\nShort")

bgcolor(color = IncludeFilter and FilterLong ? lime : IncludeFilter and FilterShort ? red : na, title = "Filter Background")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how we use:

```
if enterLong
    inLong := true
    entryPrice := close
else if enterShort
    inShort := true
    entryPrice := close
else if exitLong
    inLong := false
    entryPrice := na
else if exitShort
    inShort := false
    entryPrice := na
```

in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738873/managing-longs-and-short-orders-like-lucf-pinecoders-backtesting-trading-engine?noredirect=1#comment119793277_67738873).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best!

Comment: Could you also please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761324/time-is-not-a-valid-type-keyword-in-variable-declaration because it's part of the strategy, even tho it was answered, I would like to hear your thoughts because you are the conventions guy.